# Apply function to Dictionary of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary of dataframes, Di_N. How can I apply the same functions to each dataframe please?

The names of the dataframes are generated from the data so these are not defined in the code.

The following code has been edited to use JPP's answer; "Iterate your dictionary keys and modify the dataframe for each key sequentially":

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
import copy

# Data
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Box' : [1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1007,1007,1007,1007,1008,1008,1008,1009,1009,1010,1011,1011,1012,1013],
                     'Item': [  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  40,  43,  44,  45,  43,  44,  45,  40,  41,  40,  44,  45,  44,  45]})


df_Y = pd.DataFrame({'Box' : [1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,1011,1012,1013,1014],
                     'Type': [ 103, 101, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 103]})

# Find whether each Box contains each Item
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return 1
    except ValueError:
        return 0
df_1['Thing'] = df_1['Item'].apply(is_number)

# Join
df_N = df_1.set_index('Box').join(df_Y.set_index('Box', 'outer')) # Why isn't Box 1014 in df_N?

# Find how many Boxes there are of each Type
def fun(g):
    try:
        return float(g.shape[0])
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return np.nan
df_T = df_Y.groupby('Type').apply(fun).to_frame().transpose()

# Map of Box Type
Ma_G = df_N.groupby('Type')

# Group the Boxes by Type
Di_1 = {}
for name, group in Ma_G:
    Di_1[str(name)] = group

Di_2 = copy.deepcopy(Di_1)
Di_3 = {}

# Function to find the Mean of how many times each Item is in a Box
def fun(g):
    try:
        return float(g.shape[0])
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return np.nan

numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']

for k in Di_1:

    # Table of which Item is in which Box
    Di_2[k] = pd.pivot_table(Di_1[k], values='Thing', columns='Item', index=['Box'], aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)

    # Find the Mean of how many times each Item is in a Box
    Di_3[k] = Di_1[k] .groupby('Item') .apply(fun)  .to_frame() .transpose()
    Di_3[k] = (Di_3[k].loc[0] / len(Di_1[k].index)) .to_frame() .transpose()

Di_4 = copy.deepcopy(Di_2)
for k in Di_1:

    # Compare each Box to the Mean - is this valid?
    Di_4[k] = pd.DataFrame(Di_2[k].values - Di_3[k].values, columns=Di_2[k].columns, index=Di_2[k].index)

    for c in [c for c in Di_4[k].columns if Di_4[k][c].dtype in numerics]:
        Di_4[k][c] = Di_4[k][c].abs()

    Di_2[k]['Unusualness'] = Di_4[k].sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate your dictionary keys and modify the dataframe for each key sequentially. Here's some pseudo-code to demonstrate how you can do this:

```
for k in Di_N:
    Di_N[k] = pd.pivot_table(Di_N[k], values='Thing', ...).fillna(0)
    ....
    df_3 = ....
    df_4 = pd.DataFrame(Di_N[k].values - .... )
    Di_N[k]['Unusualness'] = df_4.sum(axis=1)
```

There are a few bits you *don't* need to include in your loop, e.g. definition of `fun()` and `numerics`. Put these outside your loop, you can still reference these objects within your loop.

In addition, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to select numeric columns:

```
num_cols = df_4.select_dtypes(include=numerics).columns
df_4[num_cols] = df_4[num_cols].abs()
```

Comment: That's great; it does exactly what I asked for; apply the same functions to each dataframe in a dictionary of dataframes. Now I only have to work out what I wanted!

Comment: This works on the dummy data but not on the real data, where the line     "Di_3[k] = Di_1[k] .groupby('Material') .apply(fun) .to_frame() .transpose()"     gives the     "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'"

Comment: Well, yes, a dataframe does have a `to_frame` method (only series do). You can try `reset_index` after `pivot_table`. And also check what types you are working with at each step.

Comment: But it does the first 6 dataframes before falling over & it doesn't work without the to_frame bit.

Comment: As I said, you need to check what's happening *at each step*. Try `print(my_object.dtype)` after each line, to see what's happening differently and why. Find out the line which is working differently and `print(my_object)` when it's doing something you don't expect.

Comment: Thanks jpp, I've now got it working on the real data as well.